# Eucalyptus 4.4.4 Eucaconsole 502 Bad Gateway / WebOb Version Conflict

Tags: nginx, eucalyptus

I've completed a manual installation of Eucalpytus 4.4.4 but when I try to use a web browser to reach the eucaconsole (running on the same host as CLC/UFS) I get a 502 Bad Gateway Error.

I'm focusing on this error in the eucaconsole.log What does it mean and how can I update WebOb?

```
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (WebOb 1.2.3 (/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('WebOb>=1.3.1'))
```

Eucaconsole_startup.log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/eucaconsole", line 106, in <module>
    daemonize(start_console)
  File "/bin/eucaconsole", line 61, in daemonize
    func()
  File "/bin/eucaconsole", line 73, in start_console
    load_entry_point('pyramid', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2566, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2259, in load
    if require: self.require(env, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2272, in require
    working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 630, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (WebOb 1.2.3 (/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('WebOb>=1.3.1'))
```

I've edited this post to remove info and focus on the clear WebOb version error.

This issue was solved below.  Adding a note that the downlevel python-webob version is actually a requirement of the midonet client installation.  So if you expect to run VPCMIDO and have the midonet gateway on your CLC you'll have to run your eucaconsole elsewhere.

Comment: I submitted a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by removing an older python-webob package to ensure that the newer python-webob1.4 package from epel was used.

Related issue in github:

https://github.com/Corymbia/eucalyptus/issues/124

Answer (score 0):

Selinux problem. Run the following in the your CLC/UFS machine

```
    setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Its better to flush your iptables during installation.

Comment: I disable selinux before starting install but I"m going to try this anyway and report back.  [root@cloud eucaconsole]# getenforce
Disabled

Comment: No luck.  [root@cloud eucaconsole]#  setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
setsebool:  SELinux is disabled.  I will append the eucaconsole startup log as well.

Comment: As for iptables stuff I agree.  I started with them blank and aspired to keep them so, or at least simple but the VPCMIDO steps require NATing and routing so I have to have them enabled and configured at least in a basic way.  The excerpt I provided is abbreviated and doesn't show some extra stuff for NAT'd VPCMIDO networks.

Comment: Try enabling selinux and run the command to allow HTTP proxy to backend. Eucalyptus packages by default install selinux policies and they recommend selinux enabled. This also helps VPCMIDO network. I suggest you disable OS firewall during installation and add iptables after you get everything working.

Comment: I submitted a bug report for the WebOB version incompatibility I've noted in my edit.  Thanks for the help in any case.